# Styling multiple while loop results, getting them next to each other?

Tags: php, html, css, while-loop, styling

I have a search form the searches through a packaging database. Everything works fine and dandy, when the search from is submitted I get returned results on a different page displayed in styled boxes with a picture. But unfortunately the seem to display one after another underneath each other. Although it is good that they are returning and I am getting the correct results. I want to be able to display three next to each other, then they go to the next row and display three more, so on and so forth until I have run out of results.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
            $con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "horizon1", "D2j616H5O@Lw");
                   mysql_select_db ("horizon1_delyn", $con);

            if (!$con)
                { 
                    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
                }

            $descrip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descrip']); 
            $depth   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['depth']);
            $varWidth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['traywidth']);
            $varHeight= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trayheight']);
            $varRange = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trayrange']);
            $varType  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['traytype']);
            $varShape = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trayshape']);
            $varImage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imagename']);

            if (isset($varHeight) && !empty($varHeight)) {
                    $low  = ($varHeight."00");
                    $high = ($varHeight."99");
                } else {
                    $low  = ("000");
                    $high = ("999");
                }

            if (isset($varWidth) && !empty($varWidth)) {
                    $min  = ($varWidth."00");
                    $max = ($varWidth."99");
                } else {
                    $min  = ("000");
                    $max = ("999");
                }   


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM range WHERE 
                        description LIKE '%".$descrip."%'  
                    AND trayrange   LIKE '%".$varRange."%' 
                    AND traytype    LIKE '%".$varType."%' 
                    AND trayshape   LIKE '%".$varShape."%'
                    AND traywidth   BETWEEN '".$min."'  AND '".$max."' 
                    AND trayheight  BETWEEN '".$low."' AND '".$high."' ";


                $r_query = mysql_query($sql);  

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)) 
                    { 
                        echo '<div id="results">';
                        echo '<p class="image">
                                <img src="   '. $row['imagename'] . '" width="150" length="80"> 
                                    </p>';
                        echo '<div id="table"><br />
                                <strong> Tool Code: </strong>  '. $row['toolcode'];
                        echo '<br /><strong> Description: </strong> '. $row['description']; 
                        echo '<br /><strong> Tray range: </strong> '. $row['trayrange']; 
                        echo '<br /><strong> Tray type:  </strong> '. $row['traytype'];
                        echo '<br /><strong> Tray size:  </strong> '. $row['traysize']; 
                        echo '<br /><strong> Tray shape: </strong> '. $row['trayshape'] . '</div>' . '<br />';
                        echo '<a href="enquire.html">Enquiry Page</a> <br />' . 
                             '<a href="packingtest.html">Back to Search</a>';
                        echo '</div>' . '<br />';
                    }
                if (mysql_num_rows($r_query) <= 0){
                    echo 'No results match your search, please try again';
               }
        ?>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
   <style>
 #boxes {
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
display: block;
}
 #results {
width: 212px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #E8CF24;
display: block;
    overflow:auto;

font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
font-color: #FFF;

border: 2px solid #cccccc;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;

-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
}
 #table {
margin-top: 10px;
width: 200px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #FFF;
display: block;
    overflow:auto;

border: 2px solid #cccccc;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;

-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
}
 .image {
margin-left: 28px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
 a:link {
color: #000423;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
}
 </style>
```

I have tried to edit it with the CSS but I can change the position and padding, margins and so on forth. But I can't get them to align next to each other.

Anyone able to help? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do NOT use the mysql_* functions anymore, they are being deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: Thanks man, I have been told this. I will be using it in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your css add this to your #results selector.

```
#results {
   float:left
}
```

EDIT: Sorry that was not the correct answer. Delete the above code and look into thee below code.

Replace the while loop with the below code.

EDIT: Dont forget to initialize the $count variable. ($count = 0;) 
Just copy-paste the code and it should work for you.

```
   $count = 0;
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)) 
    { 

        $t = $count%3;
        echo ($t==2) ?  '<div id="results">' : '<div id="results" style="float:left">';

        echo '<p class="image">
                <img src="   '. $row['imagename'] . '" width="150" length="80"> 
                    </p>';
        echo '<div id="table"><br />
                <strong> Tool Code: </strong>  '. $row['toolcode'];
        echo '<br /><strong> Description: </strong> '. $row['description']; 
        echo '<br /><strong> Tray range: </strong> '. $row['trayrange']; 
        echo '<br /><strong> Tray type:  </strong> '. $row['traytype'];
        echo '<br /><strong> Tray size:  </strong> '. $row['traysize']; 
        echo '<br /><strong> Tray shape: </strong> '. $row['trayshape'] . '</div>' . '<br />';
        echo '<a href="enquire.html">Enquiry Page</a> <br />' . 
             '<a href="packingtest.html">Back to Search</a>';
        echo '</div>';

        $count++;
    }
```

This is what i get. I didnt use the css file.

[image]

Comment: It still displays one underneath and then continuously doing that. Hmmm.

Comment: Did you add this line echo ($count == 3) ?  '<div id="results">' : '<div id="results" style="float:left">';

Comment: I added the whole code as a test, it changed the margins of each of the boxes, but unfortunately didn't display them in line with each other.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.
Please replace that line with this:
$t = $count%3;
   echo ($t==2) ?  '<div id="results">' : '<div id="results" style="float:left">';

Comment: Also remove that <br> tag from down.

It should end like echo '</div>';

Comment: It works, thanks man. Just need to style it now so they line up together and are not slightly jumbled due to their different sizes.

Comment: Your above is exactly how it is, but when the data is entered some of the names of the packets are long and break onto the next line because of auto resizing. So I am just going to create a margin safe enough for everything to fit. 

No worries, thanks very much for the help!